# Difficult ring-theory problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring with at least 2 elements. If we know that $R$ is not a field and $x^2=x$ for any $x \in R$, where $x$ is not invertible, prove that:

a) $a+x$ is not invertible, $\forall a,x\in R$, where $a$ is invertible and $x$ is not invertible, $x \neq0$ 
b)$x^2=x, \forall x\in R$

**My solution, which is not correct:**

---

**a)** Let $U(R)$ be the group of invertible elements from $R$.

Obviously, if $a \in R$ is invertible, then $a^{-1}$ is invertible, too. Also,
 for any $t \in U(R)$ and for any $s \in R-U(R)$, we have that $t \cdot s \in R-U(R)$. $(1)$

We suppose $a+x \in U(R)$.

$a+x=a \cdot(1+a^{-1}x)$

Hence $1+a^{-1}x \in U(R)$, which means that $a^{-1}x \in U(R)$, contradiction with $(1)$. So our supposition is false. It follows that $a+x \in R-U(R)$.  *(This is wrong, take $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ for instance)*

**b)** Let $y \in R-U(R), y\neq0$.

From a), we have that $1+y$ is not invertible.

Then $(1+y)^2=1+y\Leftrightarrow 2y=0$.

Let $a$ be an invertible element.

$(a+y)^2=a+y$
$ \Rightarrow a^2+ay+ya+y^2=a+y$ 
$ \Rightarrow a^2+ay+ya+=a$

*I thought that $R$ should be commutative, hence $ay+ya=ya+ya=2ya=2y\cdot a=0\cdot a=0$*.

So, $a^2=a$, and thus we obtain that $a=1$ is the only invertible element.

Knowing that $x^2=x, \forall x \in R-U(R)$ and that $1^2=1$, we obtained that $x^2=x, \forall x \in R$

Comment: In part (a), why does $1 + a^{-1}x \in U(R)$ imply that $a^{-1}x \in U(R)$? I don't see where you used the condition $x^2 = x$ for $x \not\in U(R)$.

Comment: It doesn't, I said that this was wrong :)

Comment: In part (b), why does $2y=0$ imply $2=0$?

Comment: It's not, it can be only in a ring without zero divisors. But from $2y=0$ we can say that $2ya=0$, if $R$ would be commutative

Comment: Why do you think your reasoning under a) is invalid? I think that's perfectly sound, and I don't understand how $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ could disprove that. Would you mind elaborating? Then we have $2y=0$ not only for not invertible $y$: there must be such an $y$ (it's not a field!), and $1+y$ is not invertible, so $2(1+y)=2=0$. Well, it's a ring with characteristic 2, nothing out of the ordinary. And if the claim is true, it has to be commutative, too, the classical Boolean ring. Erm... are you sure the claim is true?

Comment: Let $a^{-1}x=4$ and $R= \mathbb{Z}_{6}$. Then $1+a^{-1}x=1+4=5 \in  U(\mathbb{Z}_{6})$. From what I've stated, it would follow that $a^{-1}x=4 \in U(\mathbb{Z}_{6})$, which is false, because 4 is not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I hope this *is* a real answer now:
As Matemáticos Chibchas pointed out, the mere notion of "invertible" means that there is a $1$, $R$ is a unital ring.
Now our ring isn't a field, so there is a not invertible element  $x$. Obviously, $-x$ isn't invertible, either, so $-x=(-x)^2=x^2=x$. Moreover, if $x$ isn't invertible, we have $x(1-x)=0$, i.e. $1+x=1-x$ isn't invertible. This means $1+x=-(1+x)$, i.e. $1=-1$, our ring must have characteristic $2$ (so $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ doesn't matter, here). If $a$ is invertible, but $x$ isn't, you were right to conclude $a^{-1}x$ is not invertible, so $1+a^{-1}x$ is not invertible, as we have seen. Then, $a+x$ is not invertible , because otherwise, we'd have $(1+a^{-1}x)^{-1}=(a+x)^{-1}a$.
We're done as soon as we show that $1$ is the only invertible element in $R$. So let's still assume $a$ is invertible, and $x$ is not.
First, $ax$ can't be invertible, so $ax\cdot ax=ax$, meaning ($a$ is invertible!)
$$xax=x\tag 1.$$ According to what was shown above, $a+x$ is not invertible, so
$(a+x)^2=a+x$, i.e. $a^2+ax+xa+x^2=a+x$, meaning (remember $R$ has characteristic $2$!)
$$a+a^2+ax+xa=0\tag2.$$ We can rewrite that as $a(1+a+x)=xa$. Multiplying both sides by $x$ from the right and using (1), we get
$$a(x+ax+x^2)=a(x+ax+x)=a^2x=xax=x\tag3.$$
Using the symmetry of (2), we can say as well $(1+a+x)a=ax$, and multiplication by $x$ from the left gives $$xa^2=x\tag4.$$ Now (3) and (4) together mean that $a^2$ and $x$ are commutative. Since $a^2$ must be invertible, and $x$ is not, $a^2+x$ is not invertible, $(a^2+x)^2=a^2+x$, so we must have
$$(a^2+x)^2=a^4+a^2x+xa^2+x^2=a^4+x+x+x=a^4+x=a^2+x.$$ This means $a^4=a^2$, i.e. $a^2(a^2-1)=0$, and that's equivalent (due to the invertibility of $a$) to $a^2-1=(a-1)^2=0$, meaning $$a=1\tag5.$$ (Remember: if $a$ is invertible and $a\neq1$, $a-1$ has to be invertible, because otherwise, $1+(a-1)$ wouldn't be invertible, as was shown above.)
So (5) shows that $1$ is the only invertible element in $R$, and thus we've shown that $x^2=x$ for all $x\in R$.
I was just reminded that I erroneously deleted something from my previous attempt (not yet an answer): a ring with that property **has** to be commutative. We've seen characteristic $2$ shown above. And as soon as we have shown $x^2=x$ for every element of $R$, we see that $(x+y)^2=x+y$, and that (because of $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$) implies $xy+yx=0$, i.e. $xy=-yx=yx$. But that's only a conclusion from the claim, we can't use it to prove the claim, that would be circular.

Comment: The question deals about invertible elements, hence the ring is necessarily unital.

Comment: @Matemáticos Chibchas Yes, of course, how stupid of me (head$\to$desc). Muchas gracias!

Comment: Thank you very much, I would have never had this idea.  Now, I have just a single question. If $1+1=0$, does it follow that the ring is commutative, or not? I see that you didn't use this fact for "$b)$". Instead, you did a very complex demonstration, from which you found that $a^{2}x=xa^{2}$.

Comment: @ztefelina I've edited it, is that ok, now? It's very interesting that asking $x^2=x$ only for not invertible elements gives us a Boolean ring, nonetheless (where, of course, only $1$ is invertible). So.... thanks for your question!